# Message alignment to the left for user and bot message bubble

Tags: css, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Currently The user messages are shown to the right and bot messages are shown to the left like below. Is there a way to align both user and bot messages to the left?

[Current Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD5oU.png)

[Looking for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33GQF.png)

Please let me know how to make this happen

I did try going over this file to see if I can use any style options but could not find anything
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/api/src/StyleOptions.ts

I did try going over this file to see if I can use any style options but could not find anything
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/api/src/StyleOptions.ts but could not see an option to achieve what I need

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So the problem is to find if there is a solution to left align both the user chats and the bot chats instead of a left right alignment?

Answer (score 0):

"horizontalAlignment": "Right"

If it is a adaptive card gives the alignment as right

[The output will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4jG8.png)

If it's a simple text statement it will work fine. Otherwise we need to supply an invisible character.

Comment: Is there a styling option available within the https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/api/src/StyleOptions.ts that you know of which can help with what I am trying to do. I believe adding "horizontalAlignment": "Right" doesnt work with the bot chat messages